# How can I let user input the name of text file again if the name of file already exists?

Tags: java

```
 public static void textFileOpen(String fileName) throws IOException
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
                LineNumberReader lineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader(fileReader);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
                fileReader.close();
                bufferedReader.close();
                lineNumberReader.close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex) 
            {
                System.out.println("File " + fileName + " does not exists! Please try again.");                
            } 
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to let the user input file name again if exists. But it runs forever if user enter an exist file name. How can I fix it? Can anyone help, please? THank you

Comment: Print / inspect `ex`, what actual errors occur during runtime?

Comment: if I tried to enter "abc" which is file name already exists. It's gonna run " abc already exists! Please try again:" forever.

Comment: @allennguyen the point is, you don't know *what* exception you're catching. It may not be what you think it is. Try printing `ex.getMessage()` inside your catch.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that terminates the `while` loop. Since your condition is `true`, the only way to exit the loop is with a `break` statement.

Answer (score 1):

The cause is your use of `try(input)`. As the scanner has already been closed after the first `catch` , it is not able to take any new input.

Remove the `(input)` and use a separate `input.close` should work.

Comment: I just edited my code for another case. It still run forever. How can I fix it?

Comment: @allennguyen On your new code, there’s a while(true) loop without anyway to exit it(e.g. break). What missing from the code is testing the condition that allows you break out of the loop

Comment: does anyway that I can check the filename that already exists?

Comment: @allennguyen As the api is provided by the File reader you’re using, you should go to its website and will likely find something like .isExist() from the documentation page

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't close a `Scanner` that wraps `System.in` since `System.in` represents the standard input which is generally the computer keyboard. So when you close it, your program cannot receive input from the keyboard.

You should also not use exception handling to test a condition. You should use a conditional statement, like an `if` statement.

In order to test whether a file exists, you can call method [isFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile--). The method returns...

> true if and only if the file denoted by this abstract pathname exists and is a normal file; false otherwise

When you create a `FileWriter`, it also creates the file if it doesn't already exist.

Here is code demonstrating the above.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cipher {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Enter fileName: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fileName = null;
        File file = null;
        while (true) {
            fileName = input.nextLine();
            file = new File(fileName);
            if (file.isFile()) {
                System.out.println(file + " already exists! Please try again:");
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just edited my code for another case. Do you know how to fix it? 
Btw, your code works for my first case. Thanks alot

Comment: @allennguyen if you have a different question, don't completely rewrite your original question but post a new question.

Comment: oopps... Sorry my bad

Comment: I can't post a new question. Can you help me with the question that I edited, please?

Comment: @allennguyen add `break;` immediately after this line of your code: `lineNumberReader.close();`